# make a tooltipster fixed when editing inside tooltipster

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have used tooltipster from http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/

my js is as below:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../_js/jquery.tooltipster.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
       var $jq2 = $.noConflict();
     $jq2(function () {
         $jq2('#RC').tooltipster({
             content: $jq2('#T-abc').show(),
             arrow:true,
             animation: 'grow',
             delay: 200,
             theme: 'tooltipster-default',
             touchDevices: false,
             trigger: 'click'

         })
     })
```

and my content inside the tooltipster is

```
     <div style="display:none">
    <div id="T-abc" > <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine">              </asp:TextBox>
  </div>
    </div>
```

Now once I clicked the "#RC", i got a tooltips. Now I want to edit in the tooltips, but the moment I click the tooltips, it is closed. I wonder how should I handle that?

Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the plugin documentation and use the interactive option. AutoClose might be of interest too for advanced use cases.

Comment: sorry, I didn't make any further progress after reading it for two 2 days. I don't think I need autoclose? I just need the feature that when I click the opened tooltipster, it won't disappear. But if I click anywhere else, it will disappear.

Comment: Hi, I tried the autoclose true/false in  the case of trigger: hover/click, but they make no difference? Do I need to avoid using trigger?

Comment: Try setting interactive to true. If the behavior is not exactly what you want, set autoClose (mind the capital C) to false but then you'll have to close the tooltip yourself using the hide() method.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I can't believe it's so simple and useful code! I should have given another trial!